# Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long HttpGET

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

Good afternoon. I ran into a problem. I need to send a List in a GET request from one microservice to another, these strings are from 5 to 10 characters, but I have 2000 items in this list. Returns an error that the URL is too long. When trying to find the answer to the problem, I found out that the maximum length is 2083 characters. Since this is a GET request and there is no way to use the body. How can I send such a large amount of data to another microservice in a GET request?

Comment: Does it really need to be a  GET request? Could you use a POST instead and put the content in the body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Wouter de Kort ♦ for the suggestion.

> Does it really need to be a GET request? Could you use a POST instead and put the content in the body? – Wouter de Kort ♦

I looked at the problem again and decided GET request wasn't really necessary. However, I decided to use PATCH instead of POST because I didn't want to confuse it with other proper POST requests and I didn't use PATCH anywhere else.